# How to initialize a listview

Tags: android, listview

Why is this so difficult to do

I have a simple listview. When a row is pressed it is highlighted and stays highlighted until another row is pressed.
Also when a row is pressed I get some data from the row and show it in a toast. This is all working perfectly.
What I can not do is when the listview is started, I want the first row to be highlighted automatically and the toast message shown just as if the first row was pressed.
Does anyone have an example of how this can be done.

Here is my code:
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
    ListView listView;
    private View lastview = null;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    String[] values = new String[] { "Row 1", 
                                     "Row 2",
                                     "Row 3",
                                     "Row 4", 
                                     "Row 5", 
                                     "Row 6", 
                                     "Row 7", 
                                     "Row 8" 
                                    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
            if ( lastview != null )
                lastview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            lastview = view;
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xcc0022cc);

            String  content  = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("<%d><%s>", position, content), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }); 
    }



}
```

Comment: do you use baseAdapter?

Comment: Post your code here of the list view... If you have custom adapter post the code of it too

Answer (score 0):

you can set the first row being highlighted by :

```
  listView.setSelection(0);
```

if your toast is set triggered by onItemSelected,then you can also get the toast at the same time.

But if your toast is set triggered by onItemClicked, you must add other code in onCreate() to show the toast.

Comment: I tried this. It does not highlight the first row and it does not allow you to get the view and thus data from the first row.